# Only returning matching patterns aginst file with grep

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to inversely seperate a list of emails against another list using grep so that only emails not matching those expressions are returned.

The list of emails looks like:

```
   recruitment@madeup.com
   joy@netnoir.net
   hello@nom.com
   mary@itcouldbereal.ac.uk
   thisshouldbe@theonlyone.com
```

The list of expressions that I am comparing it to is:

```
   recruitment@
   netnoir.net
   hello@
   "\.ac.\b"
```

I have tried:

```
   grep -vif listofexpressions listofemails
```

The problems I am facing are

1.) nothing is returned
2.)  the .ac. is not recognized in a file but if I used it with

```
            grep "\.ac.\b" filename
```

then it does.

If I change it to

```
        grep -if listofexpressions listofemails
```

then most of the expressions that do not need escaping are shown highlighted but the others are shown as well.

My expected output would be

```
      thisshouldbe@theonlyone.com
```

I am sure this is simple but after reading the man page of grep and googling, I stil cannot work it out.

Thanks

Comment: Why is `mary@itcouldbereal.ac.uk` not in your desired output?

Comment: Are there leading spaces in your second file?

Comment: Delete the `"` characters from the patterns file. They have no special meaning when used in this context (inside the patterns file), and matches literal `"`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  found=""
  for(key in arr){
    if(index($0,key)){
      found=1
      next
    }
  }
  if(found==""){
    print
  }
}
' expressions  listemail
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when expressions file is being read.
  arr[$0]                    ##Created arr with index of current line here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  found=""                   ##Nulliyfing found here.
  for(key in arr){           ##Going through arr elements here.
    if(index($0,key)){       ##Checking if current line is part of key by index.
      found=1                ##Setting found to 1 here.
      next                   ##next will skip all further statements.
    }
  }
  if(found==""){             ##Checking condition if found is NULL then print that line.
    print
  }
}
' expressions  listemails    ##Mentioning Input_files here.
```